# Prewhitening process in transfer function using R

Tags: r

I'm using transfer function to analyze my data using R. In a reference book, I found this code:

```
xt<-data[,1]
yt<-data[,2]
acf(xt,lag.max=25,type="correlation",main="ACF for xt")
acf(xt, lag.max=25,type="partial",main="PACF for xt", ylab="PACF")
```

From ACF and PACF plot, it seems that xt has AR(1).Then, fit an AR(1) to xt:

```
xt.ar1<-arima(xt,order=c(1, 0, 0),include.mean=FALSE)

xt.ar1
Call:
arima(x = xt, order = c(1, 0, 0), include.mean = FALSE)

Coefficients:
         ar1
      0.7292
s.e.  0.0686

sigma^2 estimated as 0.01009:  log likelihood = 87.54,  aic = -171.08
```

After checked that the residual looks good, next step is prewhitening both series using AR(1) with coefficients 0.73 to show the CCF:

```
T<-length(xt)
alphat<-xt[2:T]-0.73*xt[1:(T-1)]
betat<- yt[2:T]-0.73*yt[1:(T-1)]
ralbe<-ccf(betat,alphat,main='CCF of alpha(t) and beta(t)', ylab='CCF')
abline(v=0,col='blue')
```

If I have another set of data, with xt fits to ARIMA(2,0,2), how can I do the prewhitening? How to compute `alphat` and `betat`?

Comment: Try `install.packages("sos", dependencies = TRUE); library(sos); findFn("ARMA transfer function")`.

Comment: @Pascal `findFn("ARMA transfer function")` just give me some reference about how to fit transfer function model to a data. What I want to know is how to compute alpha and beta in R, so I can show the CCF. Then, from this CCF, I can identify the order to fit transfer function model. Do u know how to do it?

Comment: I just suggest some tools which might be useful.